# How to keep unchanged the order of variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

I tried to make a forest plot for regression coefficients of a model with the following codes:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# Create a data.frame
forestPlot <- tribble(
  ~factor, ~PR, ~Low, ~High,
  #------/------/------/------/
  "Breastfeeding: <17 weeks vs 26-51", 0.75,0.52,1.10,
  "17-25 weeks vs 26-51", 0.81, 0.50, 1.31,
  "≥52 weeks vs 26-51", 1.20, 0.88, 1.63,
  
  "Mother's age", 0.99, 0.96, 1.02,
  
  "Mother's education: High school vs tertiary", 1.64, 1.14, 2.36,
  "Vocational vs tertiary",1.31, 0.92, 1.86,
  
  "Mother's country of birth: UK/Ireland vs AU/NZ", 0.53, 0.17, 1.63,
  "India vs AU/NZ",1.66, 1.05, 2.61,
  "Asia-except India vs AU/NZ",1.86,1.28,2.69,
  "Other vs AU/NZ",0.83, 0.43, 1.58,
  
  "IRSAD: 1 vs 5", 1.48, 0.77, 2.83,
  "2 vs 5", 1.47, 0.79, 2.78,
  "3 vs 5", 1.09, 0.56, 2.14,
  "4 vs 5", 1.36, 0.72, 2.56,
  )
forestPlot

# Factoring variables of the model
forestPlot$factor <- factor(forestPlot$factor, levels = c(
  "Breastfeeding: <17 weeks vs 26-51", "17-25 weeks vs 26-51", "≥52 weeks vs 26-51", 
  "Mother's age", "Mother's education: High school vs tertiary", 
  "Vocational vs tertiary", "Mother's country of birth: UK/Ireland vs AU/NZ", 
  "India vs AU/NZ", "Asia-except India vs AU/NZ", "Other vs AU/NZ", "IRSAD: 1 vs 5", 
  "2 vs 5", "3 vs 5", "4 vs 5"))
forestPlot

# Make a forest plot
library(forcats)
Model1A <- forestPlot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(factor), y = PR, ymin = Low, ymax = High)) +
  geom_errorbar(width=.2, size = 1.0, show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(size= 3.5, shape=21, fill="white", show.legend = F)+ 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = 2, col = "red", size = 0.8) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "A. Model for detal caries prevalance", subtitle = "Breastfeeding as main exposure",
       x = "", y = "PR (95% CI)") +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = "Georgia"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "grey10", face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic", color = "gray20", size = 12),
    plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic", size = 12, color = "gray40"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, color = "grey20"),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray90"),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#fcfbfd"))
Model1A
```

However, the order of predictors was displayed from the bottom while I would like to keep them in the same order that I input the variables (starting from the top, not from the bottom). I searched from stackoverflow and used the function fct_inorder(factor), but did not work.

Therefore, I much appreciate if you could give me some tips on the above plotting.

Thank you and looking forward to receiving your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default the categories on a discrete scale are displayed starting with the first level or category at the bottom or left.

To reverse the order you could use `forcats::fct_rev` to reverse the order of the factor levels or reverse the order via the scale, e.g. in your case using `scale_x_discrete(limits = rev)`.

###### 1. Reverse the order of the levels

```r
library(tidyverse)

forestPlot$factor <- fct_inorder(forestPlot$factor)

ggplot(forestPlot, aes(x = fct_rev(factor), y = PR, ymin = Low, ymax = High)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = .2, size = 1.0, show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5, shape = 21, fill = "white", show.legend = F) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = 2, col = "red", size = 0.8) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(
    title = "A. Model for detal caries prevalance", subtitle = "Breastfeeding as main exposure",
    x = "", y = "PR (95% CI)"
  ) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = "Georgia"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "grey10", face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic", color = "gray20", size = 12),
    plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic", size = 12, color = "gray40"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, color = "grey20"),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray90"),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#fcfbfd")
  ) 
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
```

[image]

###### 2. Reverse the order via`scale_x_discrete(limits = rev)`

```r
ggplot(forestPlot, aes(x = factor, y = PR, ymin = Low, ymax = High)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = .2, size = 1.0, show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5, shape = 21, fill = "white", show.legend = F) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = 2, col = "red", size = 0.8) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(
    title = "A. Model for detal caries prevalance", subtitle = "Breastfeeding as main exposure",
    x = "", y = "PR (95% CI)"
  ) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = "Georgia"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "grey10", face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic", color = "gray20", size = 12),
    plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic", size = 12, color = "gray40"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12, color = "grey20"),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray90"),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#fcfbfd")
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Stefan, for your great help. It's extremely useful.  I just wonder if there is any way to display or show OR (95%CI) on the right handside as the picture above (I'm sorry to ask this further question).

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your help. I realize that I could make a plot with 95% CI using excel. So, perhaps, could you close the discussion. I think your help with keeping unchanged the order of the variables is sufficient.